# .find() in MongoDB with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building a webapp using meteor and JavaScript, and want to filter a JSON object based on attribute. I can run `fullList.find()` to get everything and `fullList.find({'Color': 'r'})` to get only "red" items, but I want to return all items that are either "red" or "blue", and can't figure out the proper syntax. I've tried various combinations such as `fullList.find({'Color': 'r' || 'b'})` and `fullList.find({'Color': ('r' || 'b')})`, but it either doesn't run at all or returns items with only one attribute, rather than returning items with either. I feel like this should be an easy fix, I'm just not very familiar with JavaScript.

Here's my (relevant) code for completeness. Only the logic for two conditions being true (as opposed to one or three) is failing:

```js
indicadores: function(){
        if (Session.get("displayUrgencies")){
            if (Session.get("displayInsuff")){
                if (Session.get("displayStrengths")){
                    console.log("display all");
                    return fullList.find();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("display urgencies and insufficiencies");
                    return fullList.find({'Color': 'v' || 'r'});
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Session.get("displayStrengths")){
                    console.log("display urgencies and strengths");
                    return fullList.find({'Color': 'b' || 'r'});
                }
                else {
                    console.log("display urgencies");
                    return fullList.find({'Color': 'r'});
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Session.get("displayInsuff")){
            if (Session.get("displayStrengths")){
                console.log("display insufficiencies and strengths");
                return fullList.find({'Color': 'v' || 'b'});
            }
            else {
                console.log("display insufficiencies");
                return fullList.find({'Color': 'v'});
            }
        }
        else if (Session.get("displayStrengths")){
            console.log("display strengths");
            return fullList.find({'Color': 'b'});
        }
        else {
            console.log("display all (default)");
            return fullList.find();
        }       
    },
```

Comment: As you currently have it, the second return never runs. It evaluates the statement in the first return, then returns, stopping execution.

Comment: That was accidentally left in from me trying anything I could think of; it still doesn't work without the second return. I'll edit the code to reflect the way it actually is now; sorry about that

Comment: What library are you using for `.find`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `.find` function isn't a part of JS itself. It's a property of a MongoDB collection. You can simply use the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) [MongoDB selector](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/). Like this:

```
fullList.find({
  $or: [
    {'Color': 'r'},
    {'Color': 'b'}
  ]
})
```

In your example `fullList` is the MongoDB collection. You can read more about them [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection).

Comment: Ok, that's very helpful to know that it's a MongoDB command, but it still doesn't quite work. I get the error message "Exception in template helper: Error: $and/$or/$nor must be nonempty array".

Comment: I found something in that documentation pretty close to what you said that is working for me. My solution in the end is fullList.find({Color: {$in: ['v', 'r']}}); . Thanks for the help!